# What is the meaning of "honorable speaker"?

Tags: research-process, conference, publishers

I have an email from the **2nd World Congress on Wind & Renewable Energy 2017** as an "Honorable Speaker" .... does that mean presenting a new paper and paying any fees?

Comment: Sounds like a scam to me.

Comment: I don't understand. Are they asking you to be an honorable speaker or is the email *from* an honorable speaker. You've written the former the question, as written, doesn't quite make sense then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are often emails like these floating around, some look enticing; however, to protect yourself against any potential scam attempt (or worse) - as with any unexpected email from an unknown source, I would advise:

- Hover over the email address in the email you received - if it is from 'yahoo', 'gmail' or any other free email service, be wary. Don't reply directly.
- Don't open any links and do not open any attachments in the email (should be wary of doing this from unknown emails anyway).
- Do a web search and go directly to the conference website (in this case http://windenergy.conferenceseries.com/)
- Read the information on the webpage (and the fine print)
- Use the contact details there to ask questions if you have any questions (contact details at the bottom of the page)

Reading the conference site, it looks like if that invitation is real, then you will still have to pay for registration etc. and present a paper.  Some conferences send these emails as an advertisement for their conference.

Be wary of 'predatory conferences' - there are many guides to help with that, an example is from the University College Dublin's page [Scholarly Communications: Predatory Publishers & Conferences](http://libguides.ucd.ie/publishing/predatory)